# xpath to multiple tags with different classes and ids > output: text

Tags: xml, xpath

I would like to search for all text that is within specific tags (e.g.:spans, divs, and so on ... any tag) that have a specific class AND id:

so I came up with this xpath:

`//*[(@id='att1' and @class='att2') OR (@id='att3' and @class='att4')]/text()`

but it does not work :(

any help would be great! thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put `OR` in lower case and it should work:

```
//*[(@id='att1' and @class='att2') or (@id='att3' and @class='att4')]/text()
```

(FYI the corresponding grammar rules − regarding XPath logical expressions − can be found in [that section of the the W3C specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-logical-expressions).)